# How can i set different model for call and response using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

is it possible to set two models for retrofit POST? i want to set the first model that use Call POST to send json data and another model that handle the response from the server

Comment: You mean like sending a object as a Body and retrieve one different object as another object?

Comment: @DinorahTovar yes. Sending fname, lname, email as Call <User> and get response status, message as different model UserStatusResponse

Answer (score 0):

To get to differents objects is pretty much straight foward:

```
@POST("yourMagicURL")
fun login(@Body loginRequest: User): Call<UserStatusResponse>
```

Where User is the object that contains: fname, lname, email 
and UserStatusResponse is the object that contains status, message

Comment: I didn't understand the "fun login" this is my real line of code @POST("Payment/{tenantId}/customerpayNew")
    Call<PaymentPostModel> createPayment(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Body PaymentPostModel paymentPostModel); and i am wondering how to add the response model

Comment: Sorry, I put my code on kotlin, but I think Im not understanding your question, you already have a return value from your model, what is the problem then? can you share a JSON

Comment: I am using PaymentPostModel to send via POST payment details then the server return the answer "status" : true, "message": "payment add successfully". iam using PaymentMessage model. How can i send Call using PaymentPostModel and get Response using PaymentMessage